# Register MassTransit Client in a Backend Dynamically

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, masstransit

We are looking to implement a message bus backed by Azure Service Bus and MassTransit.  I am working on some console apps to mock things up.  I have created a `Backend` app that would mimic a server and a `Client` app that mimics one or more frontends that connect to the backend.

Here is what the backend looks like based on what I have read online:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MassTransit.Demo.Contract;
using MassTransit.Demo.Contract.Messages;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace MassTransit.Demo.Backend
{
    public class Program
    {
        private static readonly string BusEndpointName = $"{Environment.MachineName}-{DateTime.Now.Second}-Bus";

        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Title = "Sender Window";
            Console.WriteLine("Starting MassTransit publisher...");
            await CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().RunAsync();
            //Cleanup queues, topics, and subs via MS Azure Libs since MT does not do this?
            await AzureManagementHelper.RemoveQueueAndSubscription(BusEndpointName);
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
        {
            return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).ConfigureServices((_, services) =>
            {
                services.AddMassTransit(busRegistrationConfigurator =>
                {
                    busRegistrationConfigurator.SetKebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter();
                    busRegistrationConfigurator.AddHostedService<BackendPublishService>();
                    busRegistrationConfigurator.AddHostedService<RequestResponseService>();

                    busRegistrationConfigurator.UsingAzureServiceBus((busRegistrationContext, serviceBusBusFactoryConfigurator) =>
                    {
                        serviceBusBusFactoryConfigurator.Host(ConnectionStrings.AzureServiceBusConnectionString);
                        serviceBusBusFactoryConfigurator.ConfigureEndpoints(busRegistrationContext);

                        //Specify the request-response temporary bus name
                        serviceBusBusFactoryConfigurator.OverrideDefaultBusEndpointQueueName(BusEndpointName);

                        //Specify the Message Type Topic names explicitly instead of using assumed format
                        serviceBusBusFactoryConfigurator.Message<BackendBroadcastMessage>(
                            messageTopologyConfigurator => messageTopologyConfigurator
                                .SetEntityName(ConnectionStrings.TopicNameBackendBroadcast));

                        serviceBusBusFactoryConfigurator.Message<RequestMessage>(
                            messageTopologyConfigurator => messageTopologyConfigurator
                                .SetEntityName(ConnectionStrings.TopicNameRequestResponse));
                    });
                });
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The clients are similar.  Everything thing works. But for the next requirement, I am a little unsure what is the proper way to do it.

Say, the backend is running first (and always up).  Then, a client comes online and needs to "register" itself with the backend.  This creates a one-to-one connection between the backend and frontend for targeted messages that other clients should not see.  How is this done in MT after the app is started and configured already?  All of the documentation I have read talking about the startup configuration in the code above.  But I would like it to be dynamic so that as clients go up and down, they can register and unregister themselves gracefully.

I started going down the road with the `RequestResponseService`:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MassTransit.Demo.Contract.Messages;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace MassTransit.Demo.Backend
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Sends request messages at regular intervals and awaits responses.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed class RequestResponseService : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly IBus _bus;

        public RequestResponseService(IBus bus)
        {
            _bus = bus;
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            var count = 0;
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                var message = new RequestMessage($"Yo {count++}");
                Console.WriteLine($"({Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId}) Requesting response to: {message.MessageText}");

                //Await but avoid context switchback so it does not block other message services
                var response = await _bus
                    .Request<RequestMessage, ResponseMessage>(message, stoppingToken)
                    .ConfigureAwait(false);

                Console.WriteLine($"({Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId}) Response received: {response.Message.MessageText}");
                await Task.Delay(4000, stoppingToken);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this would be a kind of FIFO scenario in that the first Client to receive the request and respond, wins.  Others would respond and the messages would dead-letter or something.  Looking at `IBus`, I see options to create `IClientFactory`s but it seems to be expecting URIs and endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve dynamic registration and unregistration of clients with a MassTransit backend for one-to-one communication, you can implement a service discovery mechanism and use MassTransit's dynamic consumer registration feature.
This way, clients can register themselves with the backend when they come online and unregister when they go offline.

When a client registers itself with the backend by sending a `ClientRegistrationMessage`, the backend creates a dynamically named topic for that client and subscribes to it. Messages sent by the backend to this topic will only be received by the registered client.

This approach allows clients to register and unregister themselves dynamically, and the backend can send targeted messages to specific clients

**Code**

**Backend/Program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MassTransit;
using MassTransitDemo.Client.Messages;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace MassTransitDemo.Backend
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Title = "Backend";
            Console.WriteLine("Starting MassTransit backend...");

            await CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().RunAsync();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
        {
            return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).ConfigureServices((_, services) =>
            {
                services.AddMassTransit(x =>
                {
                    x.UsingAzureServiceBus((context, cfg) =>
                    {
                        var azureServiceBusConnectionString = "YOUR_AZURE_SERVICE_BUS_CONNECTION_STRING";
                        cfg.Host(azureServiceBusConnectionString);

                        // Register the client registration consumer
                        cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("client-registration-queue", e =>
                        {
                            e.Consumer<ClientRegistrationConsumer>();
                        });

                        // Register other message consumers as needed
                    });
                });
                services.AddHostedService<MassTransitService>();
            });
        }
    }
```

**Backend/Handlers/ClientRegistrationConsumer.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MassTransit;
using MassTransitDemo.Client.Messages;

namespace MassTransitDemo.Backend.Handlers
{
    public class ClientRegistrationConsumer : IConsumer<ClientRegistrationMessage>
    {
        private readonly IBusControl _busControl;

        public ClientRegistrationConsumer(IBusControl busControl)
        {
            _busControl = busControl;
        }

        public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<ClientRegistrationMessage> context)
        {
            var clientId = context.Message.ClientId;

            // Create a dynamically named topic for this client
            var topicName = $"client-topic-{clientId}";

            // Create a subscription for this client on the topic
            await _busControl.ConnectSendEndpoint(new Uri(topicName)).ConfigureAwait(false);

            // Perform registration logic here
            // For simplicity, just print the registration message
            Console.WriteLine($"Client '{clientId}' registered for message types: {string.Join(", ", context.Message.MessageTypes)}");
        }
    }
}
```

**Client/Program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MassTransit;
using MassTransitDemo.Client.Messages;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace MassTransitDemo.Client
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Title = "Client";
            Console.WriteLine("Starting MassTransit client...");

            await CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().RunAsync();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
        {
            return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).ConfigureServices((_, services) =>
            {
                services.AddMassTransit(x =>
                {
                    x.UsingAzureServiceBus((context, cfg) =>
                    {
                        var azureServiceBusConnectionString = "YOUR_AZURE_SERVICE_BUS_CONNECTION_STRING";
                        cfg.Host(azureServiceBusConnectionString);

                        // Register other message consumers as needed
                    });
                });
                services.AddHostedService<ClientService>();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**Client/Handlers/MessageHandlers.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MassTransit;
using MassTransitDemo.Client.Messages;

namespace MassTransitDemo.Client.Handlers
{
    public class TargetedMessageConsumer : IConsumer<TargetedMessage>
    {
        public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<TargetedMessage> context)
        {
            // Handle the targeted message received by the client
            var message = context.Message;
            Console.WriteLine($"Client received targeted message: {message.Content}");
        }
    }
}
```

**Client/Handlers/RegistrationHandlers.cs**

```
    using System;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using MassTransit;
    using MassTransitDemo.Client.Messages;
    
    namespace MassTransitDemo.Client.Handlers
    {
        public class ClientRegistrationConsumer : IConsumer<ClientRegistrationMessage>
        {
            private readonly IBusControl _busControl;
    
            public ClientRegistrationConsumer(IBusControl busControl)
            {
                _busControl = busControl;
            }
    
            public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<ClientRegistrationMessage> context)
            {
                var clientId = context.Message.ClientId;
    
                // Create a dynamically named topic for this client
                var topicName = $"client-topic-{clientId}";
    
                // Create a subscription for this client on the topic
                await _busControl.ConnectSendEndpoint(new Uri(topicName)).ConfigureAwait(false);
    
                // Perform registration logic here
                // For simplicity, just print the registration message
                Console.WriteLine($"Client '{clientId}' registered for message types: {string.Join(", ", context.Message.MessageTypes)}");
            }
        }
    }
**Client/Handlers/TargetedMessageHandlers.cs**
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MassTransit;
using MassTransitDemo.Client.Messages;

namespace MassTransitDemo.Client.Handlers
{
    public class TargetedMessageConsumer : IConsumer<TargetedMessage>
    {
        public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<TargetedMessage> context)
        {
            // Handle the targeted message received by the client
            var message = context.Message;
            Console.WriteLine($"Client received targeted message: {message.Content}");
        }
    }
}
```

**Client/Handlers/TargetedMessageHandlers.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MassTransit;
using MassTransitDemo.Client.Messages;

namespace MassTransitDemo.Client.Handlers
{
    public class TargetedMessageConsumer : IConsumer<TargetedMessage>
    {
        public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<TargetedMessage> context)
        {
            // Handle the targeted message received by the client
            var message = context.Message;
            Console.WriteLine($"Client received targeted message: {message.Content}");
        }
    }
}
```

**Client/Messages/ClientRegistrationMessage.cs**

```
`using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MassTransitDemo.Client.Messages
{
    public class ClientRegistrationMessage
    {
        public string ClientId { get; set; }
        public List<string> MessageTypes { get; set; }
    }
}`
```

**Client/Messages/TargetedMessage.cs**

```
namespace MassTransitDemo.Client.Messages
{
    public class TargetedMessage
    {
        public string Content { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Here , backend and client applications are set up with message handlers, and clients can dynamically register themselves with the backend by sending `ClientRegistrationMessage`**

**Result**
**Client**
[image]

**Backend**
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response,  I appreciate the effort.  What version of MassTransit are you running?  The above does not compile for me.  Specifically, I see no mention of the method `ConnectSendEndpoint` anywhere.

Comment: "MassTransit Version"="8.1.0"
Included ConnectSendEndpoint in Backend/Handlers/ClientRegistrationConsumer.cs in above code

Comment: I see where it is in the code but it does not compile.  Is that an extension method you maybe created?  I do not see any mention of `ConnectSendEndpoint` in the MT documentation.  There closest I can find is `ConnectSendObserver`.

Comment: @SPT As I said in my last comment, the code does NOT compile.  I will be happy to accept it if we figure this out....